# jQuery checkbox uncheckable:

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox in a table:

```
<td>
    <input name="feature1" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
</td>
```

I want this checkbox uncheckable what's better way to do this? Since I do not want to use prop.("disabled"), cause it will turn checkbox to the gray.

Then I try to use :

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="feature1"]:first').on("click", true)
```

but if I want to turn this checkbox checkable again, and click the checkbox

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="feature1"]:first').on("click", true)
```

it will send error like this :
jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: ((n.event.special[g.origType] || {}).handle || g.handler).apply is not a function
at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3:7537)
at r.handle (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3:5620)

Just new to Jquery, is there a better way to set up this ?

Comment: Using the `disabled` attribute is the correct way to do it. It's supposed to be grayed out so that people understand it's not clickable. Why would you want a control that looks like it works but doesn't?

Comment: *"Since I do not want to use prop.("disabled"), cause it will turn checkbox to the gray."* That's a **good thing**. It's **user feedback** letting them know that the box isn't available at the moment. The `disabled` state is also **important for accessibility**. Bypassing it is not a good idea. If you wan tto do some custom styling of it, that's fine, style it in the [`:disabled` state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled) to better match your overall theme, but don't completely mess up the semantics of your page/app.

Comment: @Josh yeah, i just want to try different style. But thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the CSS property `pointer-events: none` so that clicks are not responded to.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="feature1"]:first').css('pointer-events', 'none');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
    <input name="feature1" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
</td>
```